# How to get parameters from current url

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

Is it possible to get an specific parameter in a url and use it in a template ?

`{{ request.path }}

It gets the whole url, i need only the 'pk' parameter, to make a link to another page.

Thanks.

Comment: You can pass the parameter to the view and make it a context variable. That will allow you to use it in your template.

Comment: Is this something you really need to do in the template? Presumably you've used the parameter for something in your view so why not use that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did some experiments and find that this may help:

```
{{ request.resolver_match.kwargs.pk }}
```

For more info you can check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve).