# Django use the current url parameters to pass it to a form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-urls, django-tables2

I need to use the current url parameters and pass it to a form. The thing is that I'm displaying the results in a table using Dango-tables2 so I want to add a payemnt to that specific results
using the 'Agregar Pago' button

[image]

I have tried with no luck to get the values '1' and '2020-W08' so I can initialize the form with the fields:

- carro = 1
- semana = 2020-W08

and the other fields ready for the user to type the values. So the user only enters the values and are applied to that specifica carro and semana.

in my html tag I have tried:

```
<a href={% url 'pagoaexistente' request.get_full_path %}><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >
```

but it gives me the complete path in 1 argument which is not what I want.

I have not found a way to get those two values from the table, let's say from the firs row get carro and semana, but I feel that is not correct to do it that way.

Comment: Why are you passing these data views to template with context?

Comment: I don´t understand. The data that you see in the picture is already filtered, so I want to add another record to the same filtered data, the idea is to pass the parameters to the form to be initialized with those to parameters which are 'carro' and 'semana'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:

[How to get parameters from current url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40797746/how-to-get-parameters-from-current-url)

and this is how it worked for me:

```
<a href={% url 'pagoaexistente' request.resolver_match.kwargs.carro request.resolver_match.kwargs.semana %}><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >
```

with that I get the 2 parameters.

Cheers!

**UPDATE**

I made another change in the HTML tag:

```
<a href={% url 'pago_existente' carro=request.resolver_match.kwargs.carro semana=request.resolver_match.kwargs.semana %}><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >
```

And also my view is like this:

> views.py

```
class AgregarPagoSemana(CreateView):

    template_name = "AC/add_paymentexistingweek.html"
    model = Pagos
    form_class = AgregarPagoTransaccionExistente

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'semana': self.kwargs['semana'],
            'carro': self.kwargs['carro'],
        })
        return context

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(AgregarPagoSemana, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['carro'] = self.kwargs.get('carro')
        kwargs['semana'] = self.kwargs.get('semana')
        return kwargs
```